# how to sum current Time Stamp with the number of days

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column in my database which contains the current_TimeStamp, but I want to sum this time stamp with some number of days in php and insert the result into another column for example if the current time stamp is `(2016-02-06 21:01:27)` so I want to sum it with 3 which means 3 days, So I need your help

Comment: What do you mean with "summing"? As in, you want to increment by 3 days?

Comment: `$next_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',(strtotime('2016-02-06 21:01:27')+(3*24*60*60)));`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Markus AO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easy. see the SELECT. If you want to UPDATE a ROW you can direct calculate it

```
SELECT '2016-02-06 21:01:27' + INTERVAL 3 DAY;


UPDATE mytable SET newcolumn = mytimestamp + INTERVAL 3 DAY
 WHERE ....;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Bernd Buffen, But will it increment the month whenever the query is like this (SELECT '2016-02-30 21:01:27' + INTERVAL 3 DAY);

Comment: Yes, i hope that the do this. what result do you want to have ?

Comment: Yeah it does  (o_o), Thank you So much

Comment: 2016-02-**30** hey? Your February is already a bit on the long side. Now to have 33 days in it? If you run the query above, MySQL will return `NULL` because it recognizes an invalid date. Otherwise months and years will increment as expected. (Also: `- INTERVAL` to deduct time units.)

Comment: yeah Exactly, MYSQL works well in here, No Server side Programming is needed